# Issue due to scope of environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, proxy

I had an Internet connection problem which turned out to be related to setting up the appropriate proxy environment variables.

After adding lines like `export http_proxy=http://username:pass@proxy_server:port/` to `.bashrc`, I can now connect to the Internet.

However, although `sudo -E apt-get update` works fine, other commands like `sudo -E rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y`, which is related to a `ROS` package I am trying to install, fail to work by failing to fetch the required links.

My guess is that it cannot see the proxy variables defined in `.bashrc`

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Does it work if you put the export stuff into root's `.bashrc`?

Comment: @PM2Ring `sudo -E` is "preserve environment", so there's no real reason why $http_proxy wouldn't be preserved. **My guess** is that this is related to `rosdep` specifically. **Beginner,** please **[edit]** your question with some other examples as well. Particularly, consider trying `sudo -i` then the `export http_proxy=...` then the `rosdep install ...` and see if that works better. If it doesn't (which I am guessing), your problem is unrelated to `sudo` itself.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Where is the root `.bashrc` located?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Do you mean something like `sudo -i export http_proxy=http://username:pass@proxy_server:port/ rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y`. That is giving an error since it assumes the identifiers at the end are for `export` not for `rosdep`

Comment: @Beginner No, `sudo -i` gives you a nice clean euid root shell.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: So you meant each command separately? I tried to do that but I failed to change directory after running `sudo -i` and thus I cannot run 'rosdep' since it cannot see the `src` folder

Comment: What about `sudo env http_proxy=http://username:pass@proxy_server:port/ rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y` (the `env` command runs one command (here `rosdep`) with additional environment variable assignments)?

Comment: The root `.bashrc` should be in root's home directory, which is normally `/root`. So `/root/.bashrc`. Another possible place to put that `export` command is in a script in `/etc/profile.d/`. I guess you _could_ put it in `/etc/profile` but manually modifying that file is generally discouraged, and any scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` should get processed when `/etc/profile` is run.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether rosdep is already installed in your machine, else install

```
sudo rosdep init

rosdep update
```

Then try the below, installing from apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall python-rospkg python-empy python-nose
```

Comment: I have `rosdep` and the commands you mentioned work fine (except for the last one which works after modifying `sudo` to `sudo -E`). The `rosdep` command in my question is still not working though :(